# Huge chunk size slows down website loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, webpack

I have some problems with the loading speed of my project on React. I test it on Google PageSpeed and looks very sad.

**Google PageSpeed rating**

[image]

The main problem in my opinion is the size of `chunk.js` file.

**The size of Chink file**

[image]

I tried to use React Lazy to boost the speed of loading but the value was very low. Maybe someone can help me to fix this. I use React(without Redux) for this project and few libraries, the biggest of them are Antd, Stripe and Google Analytics. Backend works on Node/Express + Psql, host: Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you could give more detail why is your bundle that big.

1. Are you using custom webpack config or CRA?
2. Are you measuring production build output?
3. Are you including images into your JS? That can get your bundle high.

I also see you didn't mention React router so I suppose you're not splitting code by routes, if you have any, if not then take a look at your node_modules and images.

Things that you can do to improve is to split unnecessary packages that can be lazy loaded either when you visit a specific page or on interaction. You don't need G.A. on inital page load. I would say the same for Stripe, only on checkout page.

You can code split by using a dynamic import feature (needs to be enabled by babel). Webpack provides a pretty good tutorial.

https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

Also take a look at this article:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/